# VueJS throws errors because some datas are not ready yet

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js

I'm rather new to VueJS, and I would like to add a picture loaded from an API as a background image. However, the image loading eventually works.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
    <div id="bio" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.settings.bio_bg.url +')' }">
        <h1>Biography</h1>
        <router-link to="/">Home</router-link><br />
        <span>Biography</span><br />
        <router-link to="/shop">Shop</router-link><br />
        <router-link to="/contact">Contact</router-link><br />
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      settings: {},
      bio: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
      .catch(error => this.setError(error))
    this.$http.secured.get('/settings')
      .then(response => {
        this.settings = response.data
        console.log(this.settings)
      })
      .catch(error => this.setError(error))
  }
}

</script>
```

The image is loaded, but my console returns two errors:

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"
>
> Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

I guess that since the Axios call is asynchronous, everything arrives after the page is done loading, but is still loaded after.

What would the proper way be to correctly wait for data to be available? I tried a few things that I know from React, but it doesn't load at all (even though the errors stop showing up)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo need to be sure that `this.settings.bio_bg.url` exist from the component birth, so compiler doesn't broke trying to render it. In order to do so, just setup a 'fake' url in the original `data` of the component:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      settings: {
        bio_bg: {
          url: '',
        }
      },
      bio: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$http.secured.get('/settings')
      .then(response => {
        this.settings = response.data
        console.log(this.settings)
      })
      .catch(error => this.setError(error))
  }
}
```

This not only prevent errors, also provides better intellisense since now your code editor can now that `settings` has a `bio_bg` member which in turn has an `url`.

If instead of ' ', you provide a real image url with a placeholder img, probably the UI will be nicer:

```
  data () {
    return {
      settings: {
        bio_bg: {
          url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
        }
      },
      bio: {}
    }
  }
```